# Facing error of "The default schema does not exist." when executing runtime query inside sp using exec()

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

i have made a runtime query inside a sp and am exceuting the query within the sp using exec(), but when creating the sp i am getting the error

```
The default schema does not exist.
```

The SP is:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE MySP
    @tableName varchar(100)

AS
BEGIN   
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

declare @selectQuery varchar(MAX)

set @selectQuery = 'select * from ' + @tableName

exec(@selectQuery)

end
```

kindly help

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Use `CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.MySP`

The user you are logged in as must have a non existent default schema.

[DEFAULT_SCHEMA can be set to a schema that does not currently exist in the database.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173463.aspx)

Also you should use `quotename(@tableName)` and a parameter type of `sysname` rather than `varchar(100)` to avoid SQL injection or just errors from non standard object names.

Comment: Thanks... this was the problem. After using dbo.spname problem was solved. :)

Comment: Good point regarding sql injection. Are there any other things one should keep in mind using dynamic queries in context to security and speed ?

Comment: Yes. See [The Curse and Blessings of Dynamic SQL - Dealing with Dynamic Table and Column Names](http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html#objectnames)

Answer (score 14):

You could change your default schema:

```
ALTER USER [YOURDOMAIN\HotTester] WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA=[dbo]
GO
```

then avoiding having to include [dbo]. in the CREATE PROCEDURE

Comment: Thanks. I had issues running scripts against an azure database. I was installing umbraco cms on to the azure hosting platform getting "The default schema does not exist"...

Comment: Thank you. I created a user with DEFAULT_SCHEMA of the database name I was creating it in, but it just had to be `[dbo]`.

Answer (score 5):

It is probably because the default schema associated with the User creating the SP no longer exists or the user no longer has access to the schema.

Although, I thought SQL Server defaulted to the `dbo` schema.  Maybe try to qualify the schema for the Stored Proc.

e.g

`Create Procedure dbo.MySP`

Comment: @HotTester - sorry misread your question.  I've updated my answer

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this "The default schema does not exist" error on an INSERT statement. It didn't help to prefix it with the dbo schema even though the table was in the dbo schema.

The default schema for this user was a custom one. It did exist, and the user could query a table inside it.

I finally figured out that I had to add a schema with that same name in tempdb. I don't really understand why this was needed, but hopefully it will help someone else who searches for this error message.