# Getting a temporary table returned from dynamic SQL in SQL Server 2005, and parsing

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, stored-procedures, dynamic

So I was requested to make a few things.... (it is Monday morning and for some reason this whole thing is turning out to be really hard for me to explain so I am just going to try and post a lot of my code; sorry)  Oh - the table idea has to stay.  Anything else can be changed but the idea of this table and the parsed field was not my idea but it is my responsibility to execute and make work.

**Edit:** Sorry the post is long.  I do suggest a few possible solutions throughout but my problem is ultimately how everything is returned in a dynamically defined table/table variable from something (sp,view,function,anything...).  Please take a minute to read the whole post...

First, I needed a table:

```
CREATE TABLE TICKET_INFORMATION ( 
    TICKET_INFO_ID INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL, 
    TICKET_TYPE INT, 
    TARGET_ID INT, 
    TARGET_NAME VARCHAR(100), 
    INFORMATION VARCHAR(MAX),   
    TIME_STAMP DATETIME DEFAULT GETUTCDATE()
)

-- insert this row for testing...  
INSERT INTO TICKET_INFORMATION (TICKET_TYPE, TARGET_ID, TARGET_NAME, INFORMATION) VALUES (1,1,'RT_ID','IF_ID,int=1&IF_ID,int=2&OTHER,varchar(10)=val,ue3&OTHER,varchar(10)=val,ue4')
```

The Information column holds data that needs to be parsed into a table.  This is where I am having problems.  In the resulting table, Target_Name needs to become a column that holds Target_ID as a value for each row in the resulting table.

The string that needs to be parsed is in this format:
`@var_name1,@var_datatype1=@var_value1&@var_name2,@var_datatype2=@var_value2&@var_name3,@var_datatype3=@var_value3`

And what I ultimately need as a result (in a table or table variable):

```
RT_ID       IF_ID       OTHER
1           1           val,ue3
1           2           val,ue3
1           1           val,ue4
1           2           val,ue4
```

And I need to be able to join on the result.  Initially, I was just going to make this a function that returns a table variable but for some reason I can't figure out how to get it into  an actual table variable.  Whatever parses the string needs to be able to be used directly in queries so I don't think a stored procedure is really the right thing to be using.

This is the code that parses the Information string... it returns in a temporary table.  In the end, this needs to be passed either just the information string or an ID number or something... doesn't matter what.  Or somehow it can be in a view with the ticket_information table.

```
-- create/empty temp table for var_name, var_type and var_value fields 
if OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#temp') is not null drop table #temp
create table #temp (row int identity(1,1), var_name varchar(max), var_type varchar(30), var_value varchar(max)) 

-- just setting stuff up
declare @target_name varchar(max), @target_id varchar(max), @info varchar(max)
    set @target_name = (select target_name from ticket_information where ticket_info_id = 1) 
    set @target_id = (select target_id from ticket_information where ticket_info_id = 1) 
    set @info = (select information from ticket_information where ticket_info_id = 1) 
    --print @info

-- some of these variables are re-used later    
declare @col_type varchar(20), @query varchar(max), @select as varchar(max) 
set @query = 'select ' + @target_id + ' as ' + @target_name + ' into #target; '
set @select = 'select * into ##global_temp from #target'  


declare @var_name varchar(100), @var_type varchar(100), @var_value varchar(100) 
declare @comma_pos int, @equal_pos int, @amp_pos int        
    set @comma_pos = 1
    set @equal_pos = 1
    set @amp_pos   = 0 

-- while loop to parse the string into a table 
while @amp_pos < len(@info) begin  

    -- get new comma position
    set @comma_pos  = charindex(',',@info,@amp_pos+1)   

    -- get new equal position
    set @equal_pos  = charindex('=',@info,@amp_pos+1)   

    -- set stuff that is going into the table 
    set @var_name   = substring(@info,@amp_pos+1,@comma_pos-@amp_pos-1)  
    set @var_type   = substring(@info,@comma_pos+1,@equal_pos-@comma_pos-1) 

    -- get new ampersand position 
    set @amp_pos    = charindex('&',@info,@amp_pos+1) 
    if @amp_pos=0   or @amp_pos<@equal_pos set @amp_pos = len(@info)+1

    -- set last variable for insert into table 
    set @var_value  = substring(@info,@equal_pos+1,@amp_pos-@equal_pos-1)

    -- put stuff into the temp table 
    insert into #temp (var_name, var_type, var_value) values (@var_name, @var_type, @var_value) 

    -- is this a new field?
    if ((select count(*) from #temp where var_name = (@var_name)) = 1) begin 
        set @query = @query + ' create table #' + @var_name + '_temp (' + @var_name + ' ' + @var_type + '); '    
        set @select = @select + ', #' + @var_name + '_temp '
    end 

    set @query = @query + ' insert into #' + @var_name + '_temp values (''' + @var_value + '''); '   
end 


if OBJECT_ID('tempdb..##global_temp') is not null drop table ##global_temp
exec (@query + @select) 

--select @query
--select @select 

select * from ##global_temp
```

Okay.  So, the result I want and need is now in ##global_temp.  How do I put all of that into something that can be returned from a function (or something)?  Or can I get something more useful returned from the exec statement?  In the end, the results of the parsed string need to be in a table that can be joined on and used... Ideally this would have been a view but I guess it can't with all the processing that needs to be done on that information string.

Ideas?

Thanks!

**Edit:**  Still looking for answers to this.  I would love to have a function that returns a table variable but I don't know how to get the results into a table variable.  The result is currently in a global temporary table.  Would it work if I defined my table variable in the dynamic portion of the code and then it would just magically be there to return?  Or can I somehow select into a table variable from my global temp table, without first defining the columns of the table variable?  Or can I create the table variable when I execute the dynamic part?  The whole problem is because the columns of the end result are dynamic....... so..... I'm not sure how I could clarify the issues I'm having more.  **If a function that returns a table is a good route to go - could someone please provide me with code or a link as an example for returning a table variable with a dynamic column definition from a function?  Plz, thnx.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I used stored procedure for returning a table with a dynamic column definition**

i generated dynamic name for global table:

```
declare @sp varchar(3)
set @sp = cast( @@spid as varchar(3) )

if object_id ( N'tempdb.dbo.#Periods' ) is not null
    drop table #Periods      
if object_id ( N'tempdb.dbo.##Result' + @sp ) is not null
    execute ( 'drop table ##Result' + @sp )
```

i have sp for return periods table:

```
create table #Periods
(
    [PERIOD_NUM]    int
    ,[START_DATE]   datetime
    ,[END_DATE]     datetime   
)

insert into #Periods
exec GET_PERIODS_TABLE_SP @pFromDate, @pToDate, @pPeriodType, 0
```

some fields in result table are dynamic:

```
select @PeriodCount = ...

declare @PeriodsScript varchar(max)  

set @PeriodsScript = ''
set @i = 1

while @i <= @PeriodCount
begin
    set @PeriodsScript = @PeriodsScript + ',PERIOD' + cast (@i as varchar(3))

    set @i = @i + 1
end
```

generated and inserted data into ##Result:

```
declare @script varchar(max)

set @script = 'create table ##Result' + @sp +
            '(ROW_NUM int'+
            ',BRANCH_ID int' +
            ',PARAM_NAME varchar(25)' +
            @PeriodsScript + ')'       

execute ( @script )

execute(
            'insert into ##Result' + @sp + '( ROW_NUM, BRANCH_ID, NOM_SIZE_ID, PARAM_NAME )' +
            'select ( row_number() over( order by BRANCH_ID, NOM_SIZE_ID ) - 1 ) * 3 + 1' +
            '        ,BRANCH_ID' +
            '        ,NOM_SIZE_ID' +
            '        ,''Min.price''' +
            '  from ( ' +
            '        select distinct BRANCH_ID' +
            '                ,NOM_SIZE_ID' +
            '          from ##ResultNomSizePrices' + @sp +
            '        ) as t'
            )
```

and finaly, select from result table:

```
set @script = 
            'select distinct gb.TINY_NAME'+
            '        ,r.GROUP_NAME_1 as group1'+
            '        ,r.GROUP_NAME_2 as group2'+
            '        ,r.GROUP_NAME_3 as group3'+
            '        ,r.PARAM_NAME'+
            '        ,r.ROW_NUM'+
            @PeriodsScript +
            '  from ##Result' + @sp + ' as r'+
            ' inner join dbo.GD_BRANCHES as gb'+
            '    on r.BRANCH_ID = gb.BRANCH_ID'+
            ' order by gb.TINY_NAME'+
            '        ,r.GROUP_NAME_1'+
            '        ,r.GROUP_NAME_2'+
            '        ,r.GROUP_NAME_3'+
            '        ,r.ROW_NUM'

 execute ( @script )
```

*p.s. sry for my english*

Comment: Thanks!  I am now worried about scope issues with a global temp table......... should i be?

Comment: When I put my whole thing in an SP I am now getting a "default schema does not exist" error.  I know what that error means normally but I'm not sure how to resolve it in this situation.  The error shows up for the exec line so I guess it has something to do with the fact the server is looking for the temp tables from the dynamic sql not in the temporary DB but in the DB that this SP needs to be in....? maybe....?  i am playing with it.  (your english is great, by the way)

Comment: I think [that](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3733635/facing-error-of-the-default-schema-does-not-exist-when-executing-runtime-quer) it can help to resolve an issue.

Comment: Oh - default schema error:  it was because in my dynamic code I used a temp table called #temp but I also used a temp table called #temp in the SP itself.  Scope issue.  The error doesn't seem to match the situation but that was the exact problem.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a [table valued function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191165%28v=sql.105%29.aspx).  This would allow you to return the results as a table to be joined to just like you asked for.

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.GET_TICKET_INFORMATION (... some parameters... )
RETURNS @TICKET_INFORMATION TABLE 
( 
TICKET_INFO_ID INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL, 
TICKET_TYPE INT, 
TARGET_ID INT, 
TARGET_NAME VARCHAR(100), 
INFORMATION VARCHAR(MAX),   
TIME_STAMP DATETIME DEFAULT GETUTCDATE()
)
 AS 
...
```

Comment: Yes!  I would love to do that.  Could you please help me with the code that returns a dynamically created table variable?  I need to base the table (variable) definition on the parsed information string.  So far, I was able to create a global temp table like this which was created when I ran the execute statement.  How do I switch this over to a table variable?  How do I get the function to return something with dynamic columns?  Thanks!

Comment: I missed that in your question.  I have another idea which is to show you how to use the results of a query and select off of it.  Perhaps that is a better way to go?

Comment: i am going to just try and return it from the SP.... its not the answer i was looking for but I am going to see if we can use it.  I tried using a function (because apparently you can do it w/o defining the table columns n stuff) but then I couldn't use my temp table approach with the dynamic sql (it error'd out, not allowed for some reason in a function).  I marked the other response as the answer b/c I assumed no one else was going to respond and it was closer.