# The default schema does not exist. error when executing stored procedure

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, stored-procedures, ado.net

Create stored procedure

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.GetBookList
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here

AS
BEGIN
create table BookAuthersName
(
BookId int,
Names varchar(255)
);

insert into BookAthersName(BookId,Names)
select 
    t1.BookId,
    stuff((select ', '+a.Name
           from BookAuthers t2 join Authers a on t2.AutherId= a.Id where t1.BookId = t2.BookId
           for xml path('')),
          1,2,'') [Values]
from  dbo.BookAuthers t1 
group by t1.BookId

create table BookSubjectNames
(
BookTypeId int,
Names varchar(255)
);
insert into BookSubjectNames(BookTypeId,Names)
select 
    t1.BookTypeId,
    stuff((select ', '+a.Name
           from BookTypeSubjects t2 join Subjects a on t2.SubjectId= a.Id where t1.BookTypeId = t2.BookTypeId
           for xml path('')),
          1,2,'') [Values]
from  dbo.BookTypeSubjects t1 
group by t1.BookTypeId

SELECT        dbo.BooksType.Name, dbo.BooksType.BuyingDate AS [Buying Date], dbo.Publishers.Name AS [Publisher Name], dbo.Inventory.TotalBooks AS [Total Books], 
                         dbo.Inventory.TotalIssuedBooks AS [Total Issued Books], ban.Names as [Auther Names] ,bsn.Names as [Subject Names]
FROM            dbo.BooksType INNER JOIN dbo.Inventory 
ON dbo.BooksType.Id = dbo.Inventory.BookTypeId
 INNER JOIN  dbo.Publishers ON dbo.BooksType.PublisherId = dbo.Publishers.Id
inner join BookAuthersName ban on dbo.BooksType.Id = ban .BookId 
inner join BookSubjectNames bsn on dbo.BooksType.Id = bsn .BookTypeId 


drop table BookAuthersName
drop table BookSubjectNames

END
```

It gives error when executing through a .net website. Error is

> The default schema does not exist. error when executing stored
>   procedure.

Gone through some solutions but none seems to help

I am using `Integrated Security=True` in webconfig connection string

Comment: Why are you creating persistent tables inside a procedure? You should use temp tables for this type of thing. And for what it is worth. Authors is the correct spelling for a person who writes a book. I would also highly recommend you start using aliases in your queries, it makes things a LOT simpler.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Facing error of "The default schema does not exist." when executing runtime query inside sp using exec()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3733635/facing-error-of-the-default-schema-does-not-exist-when-executing-runtime-quer)

Answer (score 1):

First thing you must get schema name with query

```
select schema_name()
```

If the schema name is null you must try set default name with query

```
ALTER USER [dbo.database_name] WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA = [dbo];
```